# Generating all lists that satisfy certain constraints in Python

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I would like to generate the following lists in Python:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2]

... etc

[2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

There are always two "2"s and three "1"s in any list.

My intuition suggests that I will need to use the itertools module to do this. However, I am not sure where to begin, though I have read the documentation and looked at examples. Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume you mean `two "2"'s and three "1"'s`?

Comment: Actually *read* the `itertools` documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can notice that the number of such lists is equal to the number of ways to place two "2"s in a sequence of length 5. This suggests the following solution:

```
n = 5 # total length
n2 = 2 # number of "2"s
for idx in itertools.combinations( xrange(n), n2 ):
    print [ 2 if i in idx else 1 for i in xrange(n) ]
```

It's easy to see that the answer using permutations is iterating over `n!` solutions, while my solution iterates over `n!/( (n-n2)! * n2!)`. For example if the input list is `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]`, the solution using permutations is ~90,000,000 times slower (10! * 4!)

Comment: Great suggestion! Could you explain how you found this solution to be intuitive?

Comment: @richnis: this is basic combinatorics. If you're interested in learning it, I would recommend reading [Mathematics for Computer Science](https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall13/cos340/LL.pdf), chapter 16.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) and [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set) (to eliminate duplicates):

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> for combo in set(permutations([1, 1, 1, 2, 2])):
...     print(list(combo))
...
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

If the combinations need to be in order, then you can use [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
>>> for combo in sorted(set(permutations([1, 1, 1, 2, 2]))):
...    print(list(combo))
...
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 1, 1, 2]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1]
[1, 2, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 1, 1, 1, 2]
[2, 1, 1, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 2, 1, 1]
[2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
>>>
```

Comment: You don't have to specify the size of the permutation if it's equal to the length of the input list.